# Run separate queries in MySQL using a single link

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have created that toggles a material icon to on/off.
When the icon is off I need to run a delete query.
When the icon is on I need to run a insert query.

I know I need to use AJAX and am still new to it.
What I am having trouble understanding is whether I refernece the current PHP file or some other php file. Iknow I have to write my query and execute it in a PHP file, but not sure to do that. I do not want to reload the pagebecuase I lose other information by doing so.

I basically owuld like to update the icon and execute the required SQL stmnt.

Any help is appreciated.

What I have so far:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    //update the favorites icon
function updateFavorites(id){
if($(this).find('#staricon'+id)){
    if($('#staricon'+id).hasClass('star-color')) { 
        $('#staricon'+id).removeClass('star-color');
        //update the table           
        deleteFavorites();  
    }
    else {
        $('#staricon'+id).addClass('star-color');
        addFavorites();
    }
}
}

//delete the item from the table

function deleteFavorite(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "somePHPFile.php",
            cache: false,
            data:{id:'#staricon'+id},
        }).done(function( msg ) {  console.log(msg);
        });   
}
```

PHP:

```
//check to see if this is a favorite
$query = "SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE story_id = " . $story_id;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$is_fav = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($is_fav > 0) {
echo '<a  class=" stats pull-right " href="javacript:void" ><span id="staricon' . $story_id .'" class="star-color"   onclick="updateFavorites(' . $story_id . ')"><i  class=" material-icons " title="Favorite" >star</i></span></a>';
 }
 else {
 echo '<a  class=" stats pull-right " href="javacript:void" ><span id="staricon' . $story_id .'"   onclick="updateFavorites(' . $story_id . ')"><i  class=" material-icons " title="Favorite" >star</i></span></a>';
 }
```

I have update my code to reflect the following:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function updateFavorites(id){
if($(this).find('#staricon'+id)){
    if($('#staricon'+id).hasClass('star-color')) { 
        $('#staricon'+id).removeClass('star-color');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "showStoryCards.php",
            data: {
                id: $(this).data(id),
                enabled: !$(this).hasClass('star-color') //delete
            },
        })
    }
    else {
        $('#staricon'+id).addClass('star-color');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "showStoryCards.php",
            data: {
                id: $(this).data("id"),
                enabled: $(this).hasClass('star-color') //insert
            },
        })            

    }
}
```

PHP:

```
echo $story_title ; 
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM favorites WHERE story_id = ?";
$sql= $conn->prepare($query);
$sql->bind_param("s", $story_id);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$is_fav = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($is_fav == 0) {
echo '<a  class=" stats pull-right " href="javacript:void" ><span 
id="staricon' . $story_id .'" class="star-color"   
onclick="updateFavorites(' . $story_id . ')"><i  class=" material-icons " 
title="Favorite" >star</i></span></a>';
}
else {
echo '<a  class=" stats pull-right " href="javacript:void" ><span 
id="staricon' . $story_id .'"   onclick="updateFavorites(' . $story_id . 
')"><i  class=" material-icons " title="Favorite" >star</i></span></a>';
}
if (isset($_POST['enabled'])){

if($_POST['enabled']) {  // INSERT query


    $sql = "INSERT INTO favorites VALUES( " . $id . ", '1') ";
    $sql->execute();   
} else {// Delete query
}
}
```

My icons update to the appropriate on /off colors but I still cannot get the query to fire. It does not even appear that the call back to the PHP page is functioning as I cannot retrieve the $_POST.

Comment: So, have you tried your script? What happens? What is your actual issue? You mention the way to do it (using ajax) and you have the pieces in your post.

Comment: What is in ```somePHPFile.php```? Your javascript should be passing a value to indicate if the item is to be added or removed, then you php script can use that to determine if it should add or remove a row.

Comment: what happens now is that the icons update correctly (on/off) what I do not understand is how (or where) i add the php sql stmnts for the table updates or how they are accessed.

Comment: somePHPFile.php contains the PHP shown above that displays the material icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify it all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#staricon').on('click', function() {
    // Prevent multiple clicks before the first one finishes. 
    // There is probably a more elegant way to do this.
    if(active){
      return;
    }
    active = false;
    //console.log($(this).hasClass('star-color'));
    //console.log($(this).data("id"));
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "somePHPFile.php",
      data: {
        id: $(this).data("id"),
        enabled: !$(this).hasClass('star-color')
      },
    }).done(function(msg) {
      active = true;
      $(this).toggleClass('star-color');
      console.log(msg);
    });
  });

});


/*
PHP
// Use ID and enabled to add or delete from db.
if($_POST['enabled']) {
   // INSERT query
} else {
   // Delete query
}
*/
```

```css
div.star-color {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="staricon" data-id="1" class="star-color">Test</div>
```

Comment: Good solution but I'd offer two changes: _(1)_ remove the `cache` parameter. Since you're making a `POST` request, it's really irrelevant, _(2)_ move the `.toggle()` statement into the `.done()` routine. This way the resource only toggles off when the call is successfully. Otherwise, you may run into some state issues (i.e. star is off but ajax call failed, etc.)

Comment: Done. I had to reverse the logic on the enabled within data but I guess it doesn't matter so long as you're consistent on both ends.

Comment: thank you for this...but i still do not understand how to run separate queries on a single click of an icon. where do i place the insert query and the delete query?

Comment: Do you need help reading id and enabled from the post or writing the queries?

Comment: i have the queries what i need to understand is where they go and how they execute? i have one link and need to determine which to execute based on the state of the star-icon

Comment: Right, you are passing in id and enabled to your PHP script. Read those with $_POST['id'] and $_POST['enabled']. `if($_POST['enabled']) { // insert } else { // delete }` The state of the star icon is the enabled variable you're posting.

Comment: @mkaatman - i tried using your approach but had to modify slightly. See above. $.document would not fire when I clicked the icon. additionally i dynamically build my php page  using innerHTML and am wondering whether that has anything to do with becuase when i view source i do not see the php code above :(

Comment: I'll take a look this evening

Comment: You can not run two queries in one variable. You have to run the both separately, either in the same php page or do it the OOP way by creating a php class and creating an insert and delete function with two separate SQL statement then run both functions on click of the button

Comment: What is your code doing? It generally looks correct.

Comment: @mkaatman Thank you for looking, it toggles the star but does not update the record. I see the ajax code run and it sets the data fields but then never goes back to the url to set the $_POST to fire off the query.

Comment: @mkaatman Thank you for your help. I have figured out the issue. There was a variable I was setting with a  $_GET earlier in my code that went without and isset as it was always being previously set when the page was first rendered . As a result when this page was being called for the toggling it was not set and it caused everything afterwards to fail. It is all working now. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Use prepared statements because you're opening yourself to injection attacks.

Try this query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE story_id = ?";
$sql= $conn->prepare($query);
$sql->bind_param("s", $story_id);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->getResult();
print_r($result);
```